# Where can I modify discourageImplicitMeasures?

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a model deployed, with
**"discourageImplicitMeasures": true**

set to true:

[image]

But I do not see it in the properties in VS:

[image]

So, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where this is in the UI, but this method will work. Go to the **Solution Explorer** pane and right click **Model.bim** and select **View Code**. You can then edit the JSON version of the model. When you are done, right click **Model.bim** and select **View Designer** to switch back.

[image: View code]